# $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y)$, when $x^2≠-y$ and $0$ when $x^2=-y$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Consider the function $f:R^2->R$ defined by 
$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
xy/(x^2+y),  & \text{if $y≠-x^2$} \\
0, & \text{if $y=-x^2$}
\end{cases}$$
then which of the following is correct:

A) directional derivative does not exist at $(0,0)$
B) f is continuous at $(0,0)$
c) f is differentiable at $(0,0)$
d) each directional derivative exists at $(0,0)$ but f is not continuous

I used polar coordinates to support continuity, using $x=rcosѲ$, $y=rsinѲ$, I found that the limit is equal to $0$ which implies that function is continuous. but the answer says option D.

Also, when do we say that function is not differentiable while calculating $df=f(h,k)-f(0,0)=Ah+Bk+фh+Ѱk$ where A=partial derivative of f with respect to x and B= partial derivative of f with respect to y, and $ф,Ѱ$ are function of $(x,y)$ which tend to zero as $(h,k)->(0,0)$.
is it said to be not differentiable when we arrive at the point with only $Ѳ$?

Answer (score 0):

Go along the path $x= y^2$, to know that it's not continuous.

Comment: going along it gives $limit my^2/(m^2 y^3+1)=0$ implying continuity.

Comment: It gives $ y^3/ y^4 +y$. Limit of this is......

Comment: i am not getting your point, wont the limit be zero itself?

Comment: No. The limit doesn't exist. You have power of y greater in denominator than numerator

Comment: right, but what if i do using polar coordinates?

Comment: I don't know where you would have gone wrong. But try it Cartesian. It's easier